# Calling a function with input arguments in multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a function which several threads may call it simultaneously. This function has an input argument. For example, Please consider the following function:

```
bool MyClass::run(QString moduleName)
{
    qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();
    ...
}
```

I have two options for using this function. First I can use a mutex inside the run function like below:

```
...
run("Reza"); // can be different for different threads
...
bool MyClass::run(QString moduleName)
{
    qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();
    QMutexLocker locker(&runMutex);
    ...
}
```

The second is using a mutex when calling this function like below:

```
...
runMutex.lock();
run("Reza"); // can be different for different threads
runMutex.unlock();
...
bool MyClass::run(QString moduleName)
{
    qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId();
    ...
}
```

which one is correct and better? Does the input argument (moduleName) change in the first option? (I mean when calling thread pass a different argument to this function)

Thanks in advance for your helps.
Reza

Comment: Which resource do you want to protect with your mutex ? (and `qDebug()` is not protected in your first snippet).

Comment: define "better"...

Comment: @Jarod42 I have some common resource in my "run" function which I want to protect with mutex. I know that qDebug() is not protected.

Comment: This question seems to make little sense: mutexes are usually used to protect the instance used by the method (or its part) and have nothing to do whatsoever with the parameters. There's no way to answer this question without you explaining **what resource** you're trying to serialize access to, and why do you think that the access needs to be serialized to begin with. Finally, when accepting values, take them by const reference to avoid copies (`QString` copy is cheaper than `std::string` copy but way more expensive than copying `uint64_t`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many contexts it makes sense to have *both*! The function acquiring a mutex internally makes use of this function easier and generally safer to use. However, When using mutexes explicitly it is quite common that you'll want to do additional operations in addition to those done by the `run()` method while also holding the lock. In that case you'd have another function which acquires the lock and which can't call the internally locking function (well, unless the mutex is a recursive mutex which I don't really think is ever a good idea). The way out is to have a version of the function, e.g., `run_locked()` or a version with different parameters which assumes the lock is acquired.

When using explicit locking (I generally try to avoid doing so because I can't reason about code using locks) I found it helpful to have have corresponding pairs of function like this (I'd normally use `std` facilities):

```
bool MyClass::run(QString moduleName) {
    QMutexLocker kerberos(&runMutex);
    return this->run(kerberos, moduleName);
}
bool MyClass::run(QMutexLocker& kerberos, QString moduleName) {
    // do whatever work is needed here
}
```

Passing the lock-guard object makes sure there is an acquired guard around, i.e., a user can't just call the function expecting the lock to be acquired without any acquired lock guard. There is a potential misuse by acquiring a lock guard for the wrong lock.

Comment: @Kuhl Thanks for your prompt and comprehensive response. What about the input argument of calling function? Do any thread have a copy of it in its own stack or it is common for all threads?

Comment: @Reza: you mean `moduleName`? The way it is passed is by value, i.e., each thread has its own value. I don't know anything about `QString`, though: if that uses a shared representation (e.g., a copy on write string) there may still be some issues. If you'd use `std::string` (and a C++ implementation at least following C++11) the string representations were guaranteed not to be shared and no locking would be necessary when accessing arguments passed by value.

Comment: This answer makes very little sense without mentioning the purpose of a mutex, and the clearly defining the resource presumably protected by it. Perhaps that's because the question is terribly unclear as well.

Answer (score 1):

Both the method is correct.But the first one is better method. It also gives code readability.

In first option, Input argument(Local variable) arguments is always safe.Because each thread having it's own stack.

Answer (score 1):

Dietmar Kühl provided nice answer for choosing among mentioned approaches. However, I want to add, that minimizing critical section is always a good practise. So if you don't need to lock the whole "run()" function, you should use neither of mentioned methods, but protect the smallest possible critical section within "run()".