# Semaphores and possibly non-reentrant function in embedded C

Tags: c

The following worry has come up: two threads can write simultaneously to a flash, so we use semaphores. But will the writing function logmytext() in **version1** below with "internal" semaphore be non-reentrant? I.e. is there a chance that the two texts may get jumbled?

So should we use **version2** with "external" semaphore (which primarily requires alot of typing). Or are we just worrying too much?
(Note: this is pseudo-code-C, and "external" and "internal" are not to be taken literally).

**version1:**

```
thread_a() {
  logmytext("Just started A");
}

thread_b() {
  logmytext("Just started B");
}

void logmytext(atextstring) {
    grabsemaphore(); // has tread_b text overwritten thread_a text now?  
    writetoflash(atextstring,1,2,3);
    releasesemaphore();
}
```

**version2:**

```
thread_a() {
    grabsemaphore(); // stop before the potential danger.
    logmytext("Just started A");
    releasesemaphore(); // but a lot of code to type.
}

thread_b() {
    grabsemaphore();
    logmytext("Just started B");
    releasesemaphore();
}
void logmytext(atextstring) { // no semaphore in here
    writetoflash(atextstring,1,2,3);
}
```

Comment: if grab- and releasesemaphore uses the same semaphore, version 1 should be fine.

Comment: As long as you're talking about the *same* semaphore in each case, the two versions should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

These two versions have identical functionality, since call to `logmytext` is protected. The second one is more error prone, some developer will definitely forget to grab semaphore in future calls to `logmytest`, so I wouldn't recommend it. Similar topic is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331325/calling-a-function-with-input-arguments-in-multithreading/41331706)

Answer (score 0):

Reason to like version 1.
If you call `logmytext` more than once in each thread, and you want to lock and unlock each time, then it looks better writing the code.

Reason to like version 2.

```
grabsemaphore(); 
logmytext("Just started A");
logmytext("More Text");
logmytext("More Text");
logmytext("More Text");
logmytext("More Text");
logmytext("More Text");
releasesemaphore();
```

You can lock less often if you are calling the same function many times in a row.